# Looking up a word's sentences in a corpus of 15 million words

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, corpus, linguistics

I have a corpus of 15 million words, which I'd like to store in a database. I'd then like to be able to find for a given word, its context within the corpus. For example, for the word "friends" I might select the following, where I am also selection five words before and after each "friends":

```
... night i went to my FRIENDS house for a cup of tea ...
... what did you say my FRIENDS cat is sick and ...
... if you like my FRIENDS dad can pick you up ...
```

How best might I organise my database to efficiently select for a given word in such a manner? I usually use sqlite when I need a database but maybe something else is better in this case.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking to implement [Full Text Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search).  A database may not be the best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find a word in a corpus, then you need full text search capabilities.  SQLite does actually offer such capabilities as an extension, which are explained [here](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#appendix_a).

Full text search is going to return the *document* that matches a given query.  You will first need to break up the corpus into separate documents.  Usually, this is a very easy task -- the documents might be emails, or customer service records, or doctor's notes, or reports, or whatever.  However, you do not describe what the documents are in your case.

I am not at all familiar with the full-text extensions to SQLite.  You might consider other database solutions like MySQL which also offer full text support.